# If Statement doesn't read input

Tags: python, if-statement, input

Just learning how to code, and wanted to make a small program to see what I know.

```
n = int(input("Pick a number any Number: "))
if  n > 100:
    print ("No... Not that Number")
else:
    answer = input("Would you like to know your number?")
    if answer == "Y" or "Yes" or "y" or "yes":
        print ("Your number is %s" % (n))
    elif answer == "N" or "No" or "n" or "no" or "NO":
        print ("Oh, well that's a shame then.")
    else:
        print ("Please type Yes or No")

input("Press Enter/Return to Exit")
```

Everything works, except for the second `if` statement, which doesn't follow any of the data entered into `input`. Any reason why it does this?

Comment: correct the indentation first

Comment: Is that the whole code or is this the body of a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't human, it doesn't understand

```
 if answer == "Y" or "Yes"
```

The way you mean it to. You should do

```
if answer == 'Y' or answer == 'Yes'
```

Or even better

```
if answer in ('Yes', 'Y', 'yes', 'y')
```

Or even shorter

```
if answer.lower() in ('yes', 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` has a higher precedence than `or`. So, in the `if` condition your're checking whether `answer == 'Y'` and then `or`ing this boolean expression with `"Yes"`, which is a non-`None` string, so it evaluates as `True`. Instead, you should use the `in` operator to check if `answer` is one of the values you're interested in:

```
if answer in ("Y", "Yes", "y", "yes"):
    print ("Your number is %s" % (n))
elif answer in ("N", "No", "n", "no", "NO"):
    print ("Oh, well that's a shame then.")
else:
    print ("Please type Yes or No")
```

Comment: Even if the precedence was altered, it would not work; `or` simply doesn't follow English grammar rules.